# Simplify FFmpeg amerge and volume customization

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 3 consecutive FFmpeg commands that will customize the volume of an audio, customize the volume of a video, and `amerge` audio and video to a final output.

First command, edit volume level of a mp3 File

```
  ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -vol 100 music2.mp3
```

Second command, edit volume level of a mp4 file

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vol 200 video2.mp4
```

Third command,merge `music2.mp3`and`video2.mp4`

```
ffmpeg -i music2.mp3 -i ruby.mp4 -filter_complex \
    "[0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]" \
    -map 1:v -map "[out]" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -shortest video2.mp4
```

Is there an easy way to simplify and breakdown processes into just one process/command?

I've tried this one, but not working:

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -vol 100 -i video.mp4 -vol 200 -filter_complex \
    "[0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]" \
    -map 1:v -map "[out]" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -shortest output.mp4
```

**Error log(s):**

```
    ffmpeg version N-60332-ga0d5204 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  4 2014 21:31:51 with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
  libavcodec     55. 49.101 / 55. 49.101
  libavformat    55. 29.101 / 55. 29.101
  libavdevice    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavfilter     4.  1.102 /  4.  1.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'adele.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Chasing Pavements
    artist          : Adele
    track           : 3
    album           : 19 (Deluxe Edition)
    date            : 2008
  Duration: 00:03:30.55, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 160 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 159 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 600x600 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : 
      comment         : Other
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Ruby on Rails 101- What is Ruby on Rails_.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2013-12-21 07:56:20
  Duration: 00:05:42.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1214 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1020 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-21 07:56:23
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
[Parsed_pan_1 @ 0x7fcd23d00680] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items.
-vol has been deprecated. Use the volume audio filter instead.
-vol is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af volume=0.781250.
-vol has been deprecated. Use the volume audio filter instead.
-vol is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af volume=0.781250.
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7fcd23d00000] No channel layout for input 1
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fcd23c0f5a0] The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_0
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
```

Comment: Please provide the full uncut command line output instead, not just the parts you think are relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Yup edited my post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## One command to bind them

You can do this in one command using the [`volume` audio filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) instead of the old `-vol` option (as mentioned by your console output):

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -i videowithaudio.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=0.390625[a1];[1:a]volume=0.781250[a2]; \
 [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]" \
-map 1:v -map "[out]" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -shortest output.mp4
```

You may have to adjust the values for `volume`.

---

## Potential problems

### syntax is deprecated

```
[Parsed_pan_4 @ 0x244c980] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items.
```

Don't worry – you can ignore this message.

### could not choose their formats

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x26549a0] The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_3
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
```

All inputs must have the same sample rate and format for [`amerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge). If they are different then you will have to use the [`aformat`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat) audio filter:

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -i videowithaudio.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1]; \
 [1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2]; \
 [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]" \
-map 1:v -map "[out]" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Hi @LordNeckbeard, it still says `[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f951b42a080] The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_5
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.` even if I used `aformat` sample.

Comment: I have the same use case and I get "No channel layout for input 1" error

Comment: @lukas Can you show your `ffmpeg` command and complete console output? You can use a pastebin service and provide the link.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard https://gist.github.com/lukasz-madon/508d76d6fd5ff3635494 with the exact same command it complains about libfdk_aac

Comment: @lukas Can you [download](http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/snapshots/) and test a more recent build? Your version is outdated.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard with ffmpeg version 2.5 I have the same error for these http://test.co.s3.amazonaws.com/jingiel_bacterion_v2.mp3 http://test.co.s3.amazonaws.com/trailer.wmv

Comment: @LordNeckbeard check the updated solution

Comment: @Amerrnath The edit was rejected before I looked at it, but my example already mentions `sample_rates`.