# FFmpeg : mixing and setting each volume of a multi audio track file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to mix all audio tracks from a multi audio track video file. I did it successfully but I noticed that the first is loud, the second is normal and the third is low. I would like to normalise or (best), to set volume manually.

Here is what i've tried, but it doesn't work (parsing error message) so i assume I don't use it in the good way.

```
$ ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 23 -filter_complex "[0:1]volume=0.3;[0:2]volume=0.5;[0:3]volume=0.7 amerge=inputs=3" -c:a libmp3lame OUTPUT

ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 13 2014 10:28:46 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib --prefix=/u
sr/local/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --target-os=mingw
32 --enable-w32threads --enable-memalign-hack --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpu
detect --disable-debug --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffplay --disab
le-ffserver --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame
--enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[avi @ 000000000357fee0] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.2 : stereo
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.3 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'hl2 2014-06-14 23-46-14-775.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : DxtoryCore ver2.0.0.114
    ISRC            : Video:Lagarith Lossless Codec Audio0:Line 1 (Virtual Audio
 Cable) Audio1:Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable) Audio2:Microphone (2- PÚriphÚrique H
igh Definition Audio)
  Duration: 01:04:49.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 168913 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: lagarith (LAGS / 0x5347414C), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 164302
 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 2 channels,
 s16, 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 2 channels,
 s16, 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:3: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 2 channels,
 s16, 1536 kb/s
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_amerge_
3
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

Any help welcome.

Comment: You forgot the complete console output from your command.

Comment: I didn't think it is useful but here it is : http://pastebin.com/hTMeUzmp
By the way @LordNeckbeard i was reading [your reply here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390714/superimposing-two-videos-onto-a-static-image/13405214#13405214) and the last part is not so far from my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:a:0]volume=0.3:precision=fixed[a0]; \
 [0:a:1]volume=0.5:precision=fixed[a1]; \
 [0:a:2]volume=0.7:precision=fixed[a2]; \
 [a0][a1][a2]amerge=inputs=3,pan=stereo:FL<c0+c2+c4:FR<c1+c3+c5[a]" \
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 23 output.mp4
```

Filtering Steps:

1. Manually adjust [`volume`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume). I just copied your values. The `precision` option determines which input sample formats will be allowed, and `fixed` is for input sample formats U8, S16 (such as your inputs), and S32. Alternatively, before `volume` you could use `aformat` as shown in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/715634/110524) to use the default `float` volume precision.
2. Merge into a 6 channel stream with [`amerge`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge).
3. Downmix 6 channels into stereo with [`pan`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan). I did not test if the input channel order is correct (`c0`, `c1`, `c2`, etc).

Notes:

- You could try omitting `volume` to see if `pan` provides a satisfactory output.
- You can try using `-ac 2` as an output option instead of the complicated `pan` filter.

Comment: In this command, we never specify libfdk_aac for final audio output but it use it as expected. Why ? Input is pcm.

Comment: I guess mp4 container force aac for output ?

Comment: @Scandale If no audio encoder is specified, and if [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode is not used, then `ffmpeg` will use the default encoder which depends on 1) how `ffmpeg` was configured, and 2) the output container format. `libfdk_aac` is a good AAC encoder, and MP4 does not support `pcm_s16le`.