# Mixing audio into video and adjusting volume

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have mixed an audio file with the existing audio track of a video file by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783474/3405291):

```bsh
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i aud.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -ac 2 -shortest \
vid--voice-over--mix.mp4
```

But one of the sounds is too loud. How can I adjust the volume of the audios by the above command?

## Update

Inspired by [this post](https://superuser.com/a/769195/571029), tried:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i aud.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=0.58:precision=fixed[a0]; \
 [1:a]volume=0.98:precision=fixed[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -ac 2 -shortest \
vid--voice-over--mix.mp4
```

But it throws this error:

> The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_2
>
> Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script worked just fine:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 \
    -i aud.mp3 \
    -filter_complex \
    "[0:a]volume=0.18[a0]; [1:a]volume=1.98[a1]; [a0][a1]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
    -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -shortest \
    vid--voice-over--mix--volume.mp4
```