# Combining two audio files and introducing an offset with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two mono .wav audio files, both from the same source and both almost the same length:

`p0.wav` is 00:00:05.92s long

`p1.wav` is 00:00:05.62s long

I'd like to combine both these files into a single two-channel `.M4A` file. I can do this easily with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i p0.wav -i p1.wav  -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]"  output.m4a
```

.. which works fine. However, I'd like to introduce a 2 second delay into the second channel with `p1.wav`, so rather than

> ```
> <-----P0.wav----> channel 0
> <-----P1.wav----> channel 1
> ```

the result would be

> ```
> <-----P0.wav---->(silence)   channel 0
> (silence)<-----P1.wav---->   channel 1
> ```

... with the resulting file being 7.62s long (p1.wav + 2 seconds).

I've tried

```
ffmpeg -i p0.wav -i p1.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]adelay=0[a1];[1:a]adelay=2000[a2];[a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" output.m4a
```

but this gives the error

`The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_2`

I've also tried the `--itsoffset` option, but it appears this only works for video.

How can I combine these two files (and potentially others), whilst introducing different offsets for different channels that might result in the file growing longer than either single channel?

Comment: I don't have ffmpeg on my current machine so I can't try it out, but could you perhaps merge first without delay and then pipe that through ffmpeg again with a [delay for a single channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62920995/1256347)?

Comment: Probably - but this is just an example of something I'd like to embed within a process, that will potentially be running hundreds of times a day (on different files, different offsets), so I'm trying to make it as "tidy" as possible

Comment: I see. Here are some other related posts: https://superuser.com/a/714991/141595 and https://superuser.com/a/715634/141595, perhaps they're helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unbelievably, with the power of [rubber duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) I may have figured it out:

```
ffmpeg -i p0.wav -i p1.wav -filter_complex   "aevalsrc=0:d=2[s1];[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac2];[0:a]apad[ac1];[ac1][ac2]amerge=2[a]" -map "[a]"  output.m4a
```

breaking that filter down for my future self:

- `aevalsrc` is 2 (`d=2`) seconds of silent (`=0`) audio as the stream `[s1]`
- `concat` `[s1]` and the audio from the second file together to the stream `[ac1]` - so that's the audio from `p1.wav` with 2s of silent now stuck on the start
- `apad` pads out the audio on `p0.wav` to `[ac2]` to apparently match the length of other streams (not exactly clear on how this works, but it seems to!)
- `amerge` merges `[ac1]` and `[ac2]` together to `[a]`

The result looks like this in Audacity:

[image]

I'd welcome any alternative approaches, just in case I'm making this too complicated.